# onApplyWindowInsets for keyboard not called if windowTranslucentStatus is false

Tags: android

As the title says. I have an `Activity` on which I want to handle the inset of the keyboard. There is a view at the bottom which should not be pushed up. But the rest of the view should be pushed up. I can handle the insets fine using `onApplyWindowInsets` IF `windowTranslucentStatus` is set to true. If this value is set to false I'm not receiving any callbacks to `onApplyWindowInsets` when the keyboard opens.

Does anybody have a solution for this?